# Increase height of tableview cell according to amount of UILabel text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I want to change the height of my tableview cell according to the amount of text by using auto layout. I have tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    AddTaskDetails *addTaskDetail = (self.tasksArray)[indexPath.row];
    CGFloat height;
    float textcount = [addTaskDetail.taskDetail length];
    if(textcount>60)
    {



            height = textcount-20;

        NSLog(@"%d,%f",indexPath.row,height);
    }
    else
    {
        height = 70;
    }
    return height;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use **boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context** on the string to be rendered.

This is a frequently asked question and you may find code snippets when you search for 'UITableViewCell with dynamic height'.

Comment: can you please edit my code and post it in your answer?

Comment: This is a frequently asked question and you may find code snippets when you search for 'UITableViewCell with dynamic height' :)

Answer (score 2):

You better don't hardcode the height required for the string. Rather use the attributed text height property.

```
let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName : textFont,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor(
            red:25/255,
            green:176/255,
            blue:37/255,
            alpha:1.0)]


let attrString:NSAttributedString? = NSAttributedString(string: yourString, attributes: attributes)
let rect:CGRect = attrString!.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(280.0,CGFloat.max), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, context:nil )
return rect.height
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this...
it will help you.

```
 NSString *classSubjecttxt =@"Some text";
 CGSize requiredSizeSubjetc =[classSubjecttxt sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:12] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(labelwidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)];



        int height=YOUR DEFAULT HEIGHT;

         if(requiredSizeSubjetc.height >18){

            height=height-18+ceil(requiredSizeSubjetc.height);
        }

        return height;
```

Comment: can we calculate the value, which is 18 right now in this code :
 `height=height-18+ceil(requiredSizeSubjetc.height);`

Comment: 18 is nothing it's labelheight

Comment: I am using your code.. it adds some white spaces in some cells which is not in my requirements.

Comment: Actually it adds white spaces in all those cells whose height is greater than 18. And it fails if the label size is greater than 200.

Comment: Have you set correct parameter in you code ? Please check your code again

Comment: one more thing after it you need to set frame in cellforrowatindexpath method

Comment: Here is my code: 
    `int height=53.0;
    
    if(requiredSizeSubjetc.height >42){
        
        height=height-20+ceil(requiredSizeSubjetc.height);
    }
    
    return height;

}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108804/discussion-between-yatendra-and-muhammad-umair).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do it programmatically. You can easily do it using Autolayouts in interface builder.

- Just add a UITableViewCell to you UITableView
- Set its style to custom
- Make sure its size in Size inspector is default
- Add a UILabel to this cell
- Set its Top, Bottom, Left, Right Constraints
- In size inspector set preferred width to explict
- In attribute inspector set number of lines to "0"

Then add these lines in viewDidLoad()

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Also implement these delegate methods

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGFloat)getLabelHeight:(NSString*)textvalue
{
    if (![textvalue isEqualToString:@""]) {

        NSString *string=textvalue;

        string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

        UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(SCREENWIDTH/1.0,NSIntegerMax);
        NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};
        CGRect rect = [string boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                           options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                        attributes:attributes
                                           context:nil];

        return rect.size.height;
    }
    else
    {
        return 20;
    }

}
```

Then You can get size by calling this :

```
AddTaskDetails *addTaskDetail = (self.tasksArray)[indexPath.row];
    CGFloat textHeight = [self getLabelHeight:[addTaskDetail valueForKey:@"YOURKEY"]];
```

Here You will get the text size of your text then return it to  `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Then refere this link : https://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to calculate height of your label.

You can get dynamic height of your label by calling with below functions:

```
-(CGFloat)getDynamicHeightOfLabelWithFont:(UIFont *)font withText:(NSString *)text withFrame:(CGRect)initialFrame
{
    UILabel *lblDummy = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:initialFrame];
    lblDummy.font = font;
    lblDummy.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    lblDummy.numberOfLines = 0;
    lblDummy.text = text;

    CGRect dummyFrame = initialFrame;

    dummyFrame.size = [lblDummy sizeThatFits:initialFrame.size];
    return dummyFrame.size.height;
}
```

You need to call this function on `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and return the height.
and you need to set the frame on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and set frame to your label.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a custom cell class. Create outlets for label/imageview.

2.Add this method in your custom cell class.

```
-(void) layoutSubviews
{
 [super layoutSubviews];
 [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
 self.yourLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.sentenceLabel.frame);
}
```

3.In your view controller class,create a property of your custom cell class.

```
-(DynamicTblVCell *)prototypeCell
 {
  if(!_prototypeCell)
   {
      _prototypeCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DynamicTblVCell"];
   }
return _prototypeCell;
 }
```

4. In your viewDidLoad add these two lines:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

5. And finally do this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"DynamicTblVCell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

//to configure a cell before it is displayed
 [self configureCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

 return cell;
 }

-(void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  if([cell isKindOfClass:[DynamicTblVCell class]])
   {
    DynamicTblVCell * textCell = (DynamicTblVCell *)cell;
    textCell.sentenceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"jhjshdjshdjhkjdhajsdhajsdh"];
    textCell.sentenceLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];  
   }
 }

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  [self configureCell:self.prototypeCell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  self.prototypeCell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(self.tableView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.prototypeCell.bounds));
  [self.prototypeCell layoutIfNeeded]; 

  CGSize size = [self.prototypeCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];

  return size.height+1;
}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
 }
```

6. set number of lines for label to 0.
7. Add constraints for top space, bottom space, left and right space. Do not add height constraint for label.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to get better result with/without Autolayout. Need to calculate font height of label and set the position as per your requirement.

It will also helpful for calculate collectionView's dynamic cell height.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(screenWidth - 62, 20000.0f);
    CGSize size;
    NSStringDrawingContext *context = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
    CGSize boundingBox = [string boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.titleLabel.font}
                                              context:context].size;
    
    size = CGSizeMake(ceil(boundingBox.width), ceil(boundingBox.height));
    return size.height + 16;
}
```

Comment: can we solve this problem by using autolayouts? because we are hardcoding some values in this solution.

Comment: @MuhammadUmair: If you have hard coded value then why you need to use dynamic height for cell, just set the proper constraints to the field and use it. If your text is hard coded then also above code will work. Hope i get it correctly.

Comment: No text is not hard coded, text is dynamic that's why i need this.

Comment: Yes i have tried but it added some white spaces in some cells.

Comment: @MuhammadUmair: that you have to manage in either 'CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(screenWidth - 62, 20000.0f);' or 'return size.height + 16;' line. Then you problem is solved. This code is for reference not for direct use, you have to modified it as per your requirement. Hope you will give vote to answer as it help some how.

Comment: I know that.. i have tries all the solutions but white spaces are still there.. that's why i am asking, can we do that with auto layouts.. because i dont want to hard code any value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108806/discussion-between-himanshu-padia-and-muhammad-umair).