# Unable to increase UITableViewCell hight according to textView dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, xib

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with a text view.

The textView's height increases according to its text.

I can't figure out how to increase the cell height to fit the text view.

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NotificationCell *cell = (NotificationCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *ary = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"NotificationCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [ary objectAtIndex:0];

    }
    NSMutableDictionary *dict =  [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[NotificationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    cell.title_lbl.text=[dict objectForKey:@"event_title"];
    cell.description_lbl.text=[dict objectForKey:@"description"];
    [cell.description_lbl sizeToFit];
    [cell sizeToFit];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increase height of tableview cell according to amount of UILabel text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36544115/increase-height-of-tableview-cell-according-to-amount-of-uilabel-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need to follow this steps.

**Step 1**

Use `Autolayout` in your `storyboard` or `.xib` and make sure your constrains for the label which is dynamic should be like this.

[image]

[image]

**Step 2**

On `viewDidLoad` of your viewcontroller you have to provide `estimatedRowHeight` like this.

```
self.tblViewOutlet.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tblViewOutlet.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0; //any height which is like minimum
```

**Step 3**

And in tableView delegate heightForRowAtIndexPath,

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Make sure your `UILabel` (here I guess `description_lbl`)of prototype cell property `numberOfLines` should be `0`.

Hope it works for you. :)

Happy coding!!